# Strange GA Source/Medium: fzbvy-fvtabghef / efafeeby

Tags: google-analytics

I've seen other people with similar queries but no answer yet? Is it just a bot I should filter or maybe autotagging from a particular channel?

Thank you

Comment: I'm sure you must have seen [this Google forum thread](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/57848928/campaigns-in-analytics-not-set-by-me-unknown-source-medium-not-set-paid-search?hl=en) where someone claims that source is associated with a service called Feefo. There's also this [unanswered Google forum thread](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/133603083/unknown-sources-and-media?hl=en). To help give context to this post, those seem to be the only hits on Google.

Comment: Thank you! That validates me because that was all I could find as well! it was weird that is seems like a thing but not a lot of info on it. We don't use feefo - but maybe a partner does.